# How to read SQL Server column collation metadata using ODBC API?

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

Our C++ application is able to get collation related column metadata from SQL Server using OLEDB API’s (using `DBCOLUMN_COLLATINGSEQUENCE`, `DBCOLUMN_TDSCOLLATION`, etc.), but I need to use ODBC as our application has to be cross platform. We are using ODBC API [`SQLColAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131383%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) to read rowset metadata, but this API does not have any identifiers which can return the collation name.

I tried using `SQL_CA_SS_COLUMN_COLLATION` (defined in `sqlncli.h`) as an identifier, but `SQLColAttribute` only returns “Collation Name” as the collation.

I also tried using `SQLGetStmtAttr` followed by `SQLGetDescField`, using the same identifier, and I got "Collation Name" back.

I have scoured all of MSDN for answers, but haven’t been able to find any. I can get the collation name from [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx), but that will not work for calculated columns returned by queries.

I am looking for a clean way to get collation information from result set metadata using ODBC. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will return the collation_name for each column present in the current database.

```
SELECT o.name AS ObjectName, c.name AS ColumnName, c.collation_name 
FROM sys.columns c
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON c.object_id = o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
WHERE o.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND ty.collation_name IS NOT NULL
    AND ty.name <> 'sysname';
```